# I found a class that relies on a method that is defined in an extension of it. Is this a pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, scope, extension-methods, compile-time

I found a class that looks something like:

```
using System;
// no using statement that brings either IMyClass or
// MyClassExtensions into scope

namespace Org.Foo {

    class MyClass {

    public void QuizzicalMethod(IMyClass thingy,
                                string stringToPass) {
        thingy.ExtensionMethod(StringToPass);
    }
}
```

There is an `IMyClass` interface definition in IMyClass.cs in the codebase (in the same namespace and directory), but it contains no definition for QuizzicalMethod. Instead, MyClassExtensions.cs has:

```
using System;
namespace Org.Foo {
    public static class MyClassExtensions {
        public static void ExtensionMethod (this IMyClass self,
                                            string stringToPass) {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, `MyClassExtensions` is clearly out of scope when `MyClass` is defined, and thus when `QuizzicalMethod`--which uses `IMyClassExtensions.ExtensionMethod`--is defined. It seems to me like both the parameter list of the `QuizzicalMethod` definition and its call of `thingy.ExtensionMethod` ought to break. (Makes me wonder if there's a code coverage issue in the tests.) This leads to some questions:

- How does this compile without an error?
- Why would a class author even want to bring `QuizzicalMethod` out of the class definition and put it into an extension?
- Does this fit an existing named pattern?
- Is there some kind of scoping exception or late-binding going on? If so, how does it not break everything else in C#?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed some typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does this compile without an error?

This compiles because the two classes are in the same namespace.

> Why would a class author even want to bring `QuizzicalMethod` out of the class definition and put it into an extension?

It could have been done for backward compatibility: the author may wanted to publish this method as an extension when the class was already in production, without an ability to recompile classes that rely on `MyClass.QuizzicalMethod`.

It may have been done the other way around: it is the designer of `MyClass` who wanted to bring in the extension method into his class - for example, to make it easier for himself to access the method through reflection as an instance method (although it is certainly not a requirement - one can call an extension through reflection by calling a static method of the extension class).

> Does this fit an existing named pattern?

Not as far as I know

> Is there some kind of scoping exception or late-binding going on? If so, how does it not break everything else in C#?

Nothing special is going on here: two classes in the same namespace can see each other methods.

Comment: "It could have been done for backward compatibility: the author may wanted to publish this method as an extension when the class was already in production, without an ability to recompile classes that rely on MyClass.QuizzicalMethod." Hmm. I would think that if the author had to edit QuizzicalMethod, then s/he would have had to recompile. Maybe it wouldn't have resulted in a version number increment?

Comment: @Mike The author would definitely have to recompile his code. It's the classes calling `QuizzicalMethod` that he did not want to or could not recompile, while providing a DLL as a drop-in replacement. If you move an instance method to an extension with the same signature, classes that rely on the instance method would need to be recompiled to pick up the change.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your patience and time. As an aside, I feel like I both hate extensions more and love them more. They make spelunking source code a little harder, but save everyone else work in versioning. Pluses and Minuses.

Answer (score 4):

> Thus, MyClassExtensions is clearly out of scope when MyClass is defined

Nope, both `MyClassExtensions` and `MyClass` are declared in the same namespace. You don't need a `using` directive to invoke an extension method in the same namespace or an enclosing namespace.

You haven't explained where `IMyClass` is declared, so I can't comment on that.

From section 7.6.5.2 of the C# 5 specification (talking about finding a class `C` containing an extension method):

> The search for C proceeds as follows:
>
> - Starting with the closest enclosing namespace declaration, continuing with each enclosing namespace declaration, and ending with the containing compilation unit, successive attempts are made to find a candidate set of extension methods:
> - If the given namespace or compilation unit directly contains non-generic type declarations Ci with eligible extension methods Mj, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
> - If namespaces imported by using namespace directives in the given namespace or compilation unit directly contain non-generic type declarations Ci with eligible extension methods Mj, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.

Basically, this is just an extension method. Without knowing more of the *real* context, we can't comment on why this is an extension method rather than a method on `IMyClass`.

Comment: Fixed IMyClassExtensions -> MyClassExtensions. You've a better eye than me! I guess I was thrown because, in order for someone to use extensions, the C# docs say you have to have an explicit "using MyClassExtensions;". I get your comment about the *real* context. Lexically, it's as straightforward as I laid out. Politically? Technically? Contextually? I don't know, and I'm not sure what comments I can give.